# How to start Role-Playing Games

Tags: new-players

this must be a very stupid question but i came to this site by accident and now i'm somehow interested in this but i dont know how to start or where to play!
Is there a online game of this or is this only table top?
Because some posts sound like there is an online version.
And generally how and where to start playing this game.

Excuse my lack of knowledge and thank you for your help!